# UrlFetchApp to open a link

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm actually trying to make a form which send data to another webpage.

This form has a "submit button" which POST the data with an UrlFetchApp. But I also want to open this page (with the data). I tried to make an OpenLink but the opened link doesn't have the data.

```
function submitForm(e) {    
  var form = e.formInput;   
  var json = JSON.stringify(form);
  //Logger.log(json);

  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyC4jcR7qq6pFr-BYADYaDHAB10X3OeOQaB7dygWnoOT_iMmm8/exec";
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload" : json
  };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var code = resp.getResponseCode();
  Logger.log(code);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
         .setOpenLink(CardService.newOpenLink()
         .setUrl("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyC4jcR7qq6pFr-BYADYaDHAB10X3OeOQaB7dygWnoOT_iMmm8/exec"))
     .build();
}
```

Here is my try, if someone has another idea to help me it would be great !